# The nature of rhyme in _Surrender_?

Tags: terminology, songwriting, lyrics, rhyme-schemes

Consider the priceless Surrender, written by Rick Neilsen, 1977.

*Mother told me, yes she told me*

In a sense, the me/me rhymes.

*I'd meet girls like you

She also told me stay away

You'll never know what you'll catch*

Unless I misunderstand there're **absolutely no rhymes** in the famous opening verse. Nothing!

Having thought about it for years, in a sense perhaps the *you* and *catch* have a sort of "equivalent thump" (is there a term for that?) but they extremely do not rhyme.

*Just the other day I heard

Of a soldier's falling off

Some Indonesian junk

That's going 'round*

No rhymes as I understand it.

(Indeed, perhaps I'm wrong, but on the contrary it almost feels like he deliberately sets up a place where you REALLY expect a rhyme, and then, boom, deliberately absolutely not rhymey.)

*Mommy's alright, Daddy's alright

They just seem a little weird

Surrender, surrender

But don't give yourself away*

There's the alright/alright quasi-rhyme ... which matches the pattern of me/me up top.

However! ...

*Father says your mother's right

She's really up on things

Before we married Mommy served

In the WACs in the Philippines*

Here there IS a rhyme, really the only one in the lyrics. But this time it's on the 2/4 lines - FWIW not matching the almost-pattern of me/me, alright/alright, which seem to be "within the first line" (in my shallow understanding).

Later there's another rhyme on the 2/4 lines, year/disappear.

There's also a let's say "deliberately bad rhyme" war/years and another let's say "deliberately bad rhyme" couch/out.

But overwhelmingly, the song fabulously "fails to rhyme", and the first verse ...

*Mother told me, yes she told me

I'd meet girls like you

She also told me stay away

You'll never know what you'll catch*

... is seemingly a shambolic disaster of non-rhyming **and yet it is so catchy, so singable**.

It's unarguably a massive hit, FWIW I just looked it up and *Rolling Stone* magazine asserted it was "the ultimate Seventies teen anthem", and for example it is hugely popular in foreign languages, such as in Japan.

My question is threefold

(1) What do pros, lyricists, singers, musical theorists, think about all this? Perhaps I'm just off-base, or missing something?

(2) I was specifically wondering what the correct terms involved here are. For example, I'm sure there's a correct way to refer to

- "the only rhyme is a repeat (eg me/me)"
- "bad rhymes" (eg couch/out)
- a rhyme on the 2/4 lines only
- the rhyme is "within" a line rather than at the end of two lines (eg me/me)

(3) But mostly ... what the heck is it that makes it "seem to rhyme", it is "incredibly easy to sing", "very singable" ... when it observably has poor / nonexistent rhyming?!

This has got to be the most popular, biggest selling, example of a pop song from the classic era which "really sticks out as giving the finger to rhyming!" What's the deal?

Comment: Welcome! Although this post is about a song, it's not really about the musical aspects, but about the poetic structure. I'm voting to close as far as music.stackexchange is concerned. There are other sites to explore questions about poetry and rhyme schemes, though perhaps the first step is: No, poetry doesn't have to rhyme, even if it's song lyrics, and can even be accessible and popular without it. (Maybe its success says more about the music?)

Comment: Cheers. Well, it's your site, if we don't really deal in lyrics here, fair enough. (The tags lyrics and rhyme-schemes should be removed then?)  I guess we're now discussing it in the comments; I can think of no other pop songs, not even one, that is so blatantly not-rhyming!

Comment: @Fattie - You should see "It's All Coming Back to Me Now" - the only rhyme I've found that doesn't involve lines ending with the same word(s) is the pre-chorus's "There were moments of gold /
And there were flashes of light /
There were things we'd never do again /
But then they'd always seemed right".

Comment: I don't believe there was an intention to rhyme. Those several occurrences were incidental. Perhaps this made it easier to write lyrics that are mostly consistently rhythmically and matched the music well. But why did it work? That's an artistic choice, and the answer would be an opinion.

Comment: Lyrics just don't have to rhyme. That's the only answer anyone can really give. I doubt there's any official list of 'songs that don't rhyme' but here are several pages of people's musings on ones they can think of - https://forums.stevehoffman.tv/threads/hit-song-that-dont-rhyme.1069977/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I don't see any good examples there

Comment: After your lengthy post, the simple answer is: lyrics (poetry) doesn't need to rhyme. You might look into _scansion_ and _prosody_ for factors other than rhyme that make lyrics work. In this song, I think the English stresses work pretty naturally with the musical rhythm of the melody. Singable vowel placement seems good too. Do not overlook Cheap Trick's irreverent and subversive attitude either.

Comment: I have tried to delete this question but cannot

Answer (score 2):

There is this common misconception that anything poetic and lyric must rhyme. Consider this: The whole corpora of latin ecclesiastic music does not use any end rhyme.

In fact end rhyme as stylistic thing is a rather recent thing. In ancient greek and latin poesy (which partially are believed to have be sung in some way) end rhymes weren’t really a thing (due to the strict declinations and flexions this might have been to common anyway), and while this type of rhyme got quite dominant there is no real need for it. In fact forced end rhymes can at times feel rather silly and playful.

Consider this poem *De profundis* by Georg Trakl:

> Es ist ein Stoppelfeld, in das ein schwarzer Regen fällt.
>  Es ist
> ein brauner Baum, der einsam dasteht.
>  Es ist ein Zischelwind,
> der leere Hütten umkreist
>  Wie traurig dieser Abend.
>  
> Am Weiler vorbei
>  Sammelt die sanfte Waise noch spärliche Ähren
> ein.
>  Ihre Augen weiden rund und goldig in der Dämmerung
> Und ihr Schoß harrt des himmlischen Bräutigams.
>  
>  Bei der
> Heimkehr  
>  Fanden die Hirten den süßen Leib
>  Verwest im
> Dornenbusch.
>  
>  Ein Schatten bin ich ferne finsteren
> Dörfern.
>  Gottes Schweigen
>  Trank ich aus dem Brunnen des
> Hains.
>  
>  Auf meine Stirne tritt kaltes Metall
>  Spinnen
> suchen mein Herz.
>  Es ist ein Licht, das in meinem Mund
> erlöscht.
>   
>  Nachts fand ich mich auf einer Heide,
> Starrend von Unrat und Staub der Sterne.
>  Im Haselgebüsch
> Klangen wieder kristallne Engel.

This poem does not feature any sort of end rhyme, but it is still incredibly powerful and musical in some sense.

You see that in fact the linguistic structure of the text is much more important than whether the verses rhyme. Language does imply natural melody and color, and with a "good" text this is arranged in a way that sounds good by itself.

In your case you should consider the vowel dominance in the text (assonances!).

Comment: Hi Lazy, I'll look in to vowel dominance / assonance.  This questions was downvoted, so deleting, cheers